# how can I get an inner property in GraphObject?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

ma android app gets this response from FB:

`GraphObject graphObject=`

```
   GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xpa1\/v\/t1.0-1\/s200x200\/10491996_10154355617635153_5470840249552886594_n.jpg?oh=4dd714d8106d30cd7e548ad3380c7f24&oe=54924987&__gda__=1417856790_ad378b84581edeba05e0d429332eb889"}}}
```

how can I get the value of "url" only?

I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
    Object a = graphObject.getProperty("data").getProperty("url");
```